# Least number of embedded hypersurfaces which separate a compact manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Suppose that $N^{n+1}$ is a connected closed smooth manifold. Define $$S(N^{n+1}) = \min \bigl\{ k \mid \forall (M^n_i), \, \bigcup_{i=1}^k M^n_i \text{ separates } N^{n+1} \bigr\}.$$

Here $M^{n}_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq k$) are arbitrary $k$-connected closed smoothly embedded hypersurface of $N^{n+1}$ which satisfy $M^n_i\cap M^n_j=\emptyset$ if $i\neq j$.

I want to know the relationship between $S(N^{n+1})$ and the homology group of $N^{n+1}$ or Betti number of $N^{n+1}$, especially can we give $S(N^{n+1})$ an upper bound in terms of $b_1(N^{n+1})$?

For $n=1$ and orientable case, I guess $S(\Sigma^2)=g(\Sigma^2)+1=\frac{b_1(\Sigma^2)}{2}+1$. But I don't know how to prove it strictly. And how about the higher dimension case? For simplicity, we can firstly consider orientable case.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "X separates Y"?

Comment: You might need to specify some homological assumption or one can always separate $N^{n+1}$ by some small balls.

Comment: @JohnMa:  Exactly why I asked what the OP meant by "separates" ;-).  Perhaps we should have the assumption that each inclusion map is essential?  Or maybe what we really want is the *maximum* number of hypersurfaces one can place without disconnecting the surface?

Comment: I mean any connected closed smoothly emdedded hypersurfaces.

Comment: @王文龙:  Then John Ma's comment shows $S(N) = 1$ for any connected smooth manifold $M$.

Comment: @王文龙:  I think I get it.  In your definition of $S(N)$, if the minimum is taken over all $k$ for which *there exists* $k$ hypersurfaces which separate $N$, then $S(N) = 1$ for all connected manifold.  **But**, if S(N) is the minimum over all $k$ for which *every* collection of $k$ hypersurfaces separate $N$, then I think you get something interesting.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is the latter.

Comment: As per a previous question $S(N)=1$ iff $H^1(N;\Bbb Z/2)=0$. If $\Sigma'_n = \#^n \Bbb{RP}^2$ then $S(\Sigma'_n) = n+1$, but if $\Sigma_g$ is the genus $g$ oriented surface then $S(\Sigma_g) = g+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be a smooth closed (connected) manifold and suppose there is a collection of $k$ closed hypersurfaces $X_i\subseteq N$ which do *not* disconnect $N$ when removed from it.  In other words, assume $S(N)\geq k+1$.  Let $U$ be a small open neighbor of the union of the $X_i$ and let $V$ denote $N \setminus \bigcup_i X_i$.  Then $U$ and $V$ cover $N$, so we may use the unreduced Mayer-Vietoris sequence.  Further, note that $V$ is connected.

We get an exact sequence $$... \rightarrow H_1(N)\rightarrow H_0(U\cap V)\rightarrow H_0(U)\oplus H_0(V)\rightarrow H_0(N)\rightarrow 0.$$

Now, consider the part of $U$ around $X_i$ and intersect it with $V$.  I have a picture in my head (but no proof), that this deformation retracts to <strike>the orientation</strike> some double covering of $X_i$.

In particular, it has $1$ or two components, depending on whether $X_i$ <strike>is non-orientable</strike>  has trivial normal bundle or not (thanks Mike!).  Let $l$ denote the number of <strike>orientable</strike>  $X_i$ with trivial normal bundle.

The previous paragraph gives that $H_0(U\cap V)$ is isomorphic to $k + l$.  Further, $H_0(U) \oplus H_0(V)$ is $k+1$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, because $V$ is connected.  Since $N$ is connected, $H_0(N)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

So, the exact sequence really looks like $$...\rightarrow H_1(N)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{k+l}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{k+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0.$$

Now, $\mathbb{Z}^{k+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is surjective, so the kernel is isomorphic to a lattice of the form $\mathbb{Z}^k$.  This is the image of $\mathbb{Z}^{k+l}$, so the map from $\mathbb{Z}^{k+l}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{k+1}$ has kernel isomorphic to a lattice of the form $\mathbb{Z}^k$.

This is the image of $H_1(N)$.  Thus, we have shown that $H_1(N)$ has a quotient of the form $\mathbb{Z}^l$, and since $\mathbb{Z}$ is free, it follows that $H_1(N)$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^l$.

Thus, we have shown:

> Suppose $S(N)\geq k+1$, then $b_1(N)\geq l$ where is the largest number of $X_i$ which can be chosen to be orientable have trivial normal bundle.

In the case where $N$ is a oriented surface, each $X_i$ is a circle, so will automatically have a trivial normal bundle, so $l = k$ in this case, and there is a surjection $H_1(N)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^k$.

I claim the following:   The kernel of the map $H_1(N)\rightarrow H_0(U\cap V)$ consists of all those curves in $H_1(N)$ whose intersection number with every $X_i$ is trivial.

First, assume $\alpha\in H_1(N)$ is in the kernel.  Write $\alpha  = \beta + \gamma$ where $\gamma $ lies entirely in $U$.  Then the map $H_1(N)\rightarrow H_0(U\cap V)$ maps $\alpha$ to $\partial \gamma$, so $\partial \gamma = 0$.  It follows that $\gamma$ is homologically equivalent to a disjoint union of circles each of which is contained in a small neighborhood of some $X_i$.  But these neighborhoods are diffeomorphic to $X_i\times (0,1)$, so $\gamma$ has $0$ intersection number with each $X_i$.

Conversely, if $\alpha\in H_1(N)$ has trivial intersection number with each $X_i$, then, up to homology equivalence,  the image of $\alpha$ is disjoint from $X_i$, and thus, wlog, disjoint from $U$.  Thus, if we decompose $\alpha =\beta + \gamma$ with $\gamma \in U$, we actually have $\gamma = 0$.  Hence, $\partial \gamma = 0$, so $\alpha$ is in the kernel.

Having established the kernel of $H_1(N)\rightarrow H_0(U\cap V)$ consists of precisely those $\alpha \in H_1(N)$ which have $0$ intersection number with every $X_i$, we now note that each $X_i$ is in the kernel.  That is, since $X_i\cap X_j = \emptyset$, $X_i\cdot X_j = 0$.  Similarly, $X_i\cdot X_i = 0$ since the normal bundle of $X_i$ is trivial.

Thus, we have shown:

> If $N$ is a closed orientable surface with $S(N)\geq k+1$, then $b_1(N)\geq 2k$.

Said another way, if you can find $k$ curves which do NOT disconnect your (orientable) surface, you must have $b_1 \geq 2k$.  So, $S(\Sigma_g) \leq g+1$.  But it's easy to see that $S(\Sigma_g) > g$ by drawing the relevant curves.  So we have shown $S(\Sigma_g) = g+1$.

Comment: This feels a bit unnecessary if you're just trying to prove that $S(\Sigma_g) = g+1$. Just embed the maximal set of circles, and (because $S^1$ and $\Sigma_g$ are orientable) the embedded circles all have trivial normal bundle, so do surgery to simplify. Each surgery reduces the genus by one. (It also seems like your supposition about $S(N)$ is irrelevant, since you're using instead an 'orientable' version of $S(N)$?) (Do you mean to take $N$ orientable in your first theorem? I don't believe it otherwise: let $N = \Bbb{RP}^4$. Then you can embed a $\Bbb{RP}^3$ that doesn't disconnect it.)

Comment: @MIke:  I've never studied surgery in any serious sense.  I agree that my first theorem is wrong - the issue in the proof is where I I say "I have a picture in my head but not proof...."  I think the theorem is true if $N$ is orientable, while if $N$ is non-orientable, you count the number of non-orientable $X_i$ instead of the orientable $X_i$.

Comment: I don't really know anything about surgery - all I actually mean is "delete the cylinder around the circle - you're left with two boundary components - cap these off with discs". This reduces genus by one because its inverse operation is precisely the same as adding a handle. Without thinking much (I've got another question on the mind): maybe you want to count $X_i$ with trivial normal bundle?

Comment: Yes, that's it:  For a line bundle, removing the $0$ section disconnects it iff $w_1$ is trivial, which is iff the bundle is trivial.  Thanks for fixing this up!  (I need some sleep!!)

Comment: @Jason DeVito: So if $N$ is orientable, then $S(N)\leq\frac{b_1}{2}+1$?

Comment: @王文龙:  If $N$ is orientable and a $2$-dimensional, then yes.  For higher dimensions, I'm not sure what happens.  For example, if one connect sums a bunch of $\mathbb{R}P^3$s together, then $b_1 = 0$, but $S(N)$ can get arbitrarily large.  Somehow, you have to account for hypersurfaces with non-trivial normal bundle.